# 'docker build' success contingent upon reachability of docker.io?

Tags: docker

I just had a 'docker build' command fail with this:

```
#3 resolve image config for docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1.3-labs
#3 ERROR: failed to do request: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/docker/dockerfile/manifests/1.3-labs": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:60217->[::1]:53: read: connection refused
------
 > resolve image config for docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1.3-labs:
------
Dockerfile:1
--------------------
   1 | >>> # syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.3-labs
```

Does this mean what it looks like it means: that each and every one of my buildkit builds must successfully connect to a docker.io server to succeed?  Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

I tried to build a docker image using 'docker build'.  It failed, apparently because it couldn't connect to a docker.io service to obtain an 'image config'.  I expected 'docker build' to be an autonomous action, needing only the accessibility of the locally installed docker service and not requiring the ability to connect to an external service, with the exception of image registries.

Comment: It *is* trying to connect to an image registry.

Comment: Ok.  I inferred, due to the location of the >>>, that it was digesting the 'syntax' comment when this exception occured.